# How do I get my node-webkit app to open correctly?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm working on setting up my first node-webkit app and I'm running into issues launching it. I'm on a Mac and the app file structure looks the same as below.

```
Folder
 index.html
 package.json
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test App",
  "main": "index.html",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": true,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 600
  }
}
```

I then ran 'zip data *' in the terminal to zip the app and rename the zip file to 'app.nw'.

When I drag the nw file or the original folder onto node-webkit, it doesn't open my app correctly, instead it displays the default screen.

[image]

Comment: Troubleshooting question:  Can you run it without zipping it? As in can you run it in development? as in `nodewebkit app` from the terminal?

Comment: I tried the "nodewebkit app" command and it returned "-bash: nodewebkit: command not found"

Comment: Yeh, you need to have nodewebkit on your system to run it in development. Easiest way is to install globally:  `sudo npm install -g nodewebkit`. Then you can run it with `nodewebkit <name of the folder containing package.json>`

Comment: That worked! Thanks jmort253. Do you want to add an answer and I'll go ahead and accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For development purposes, which it sounds like is what you're doing, you don't need to zip up the application bundle each time. This would be time consuming and wasteful, and if we as developers had to do that every time we made a change, many more of us would be foaming at the mouth crazy, not getting anything done, and despising our roles as programmers. :)

Instead, you can run straight from the codebase by installing the [nodewebkit module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodewebkit) globally:

```
$ sudo npm install -g nodewebkit
```

Then assuming you are in the folder containing the package.json file, you can start the application via the following command:

```
$ nodewebkit .
```

But this is just skimming the surface of all of the cool things you can do to keep yourself from going insane and donning that straight-jacket!  Several people in the node-webkit community have built some really awesome tools, in full Kathy Sierra style, that [create passionate developers who are awesome at their jobs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSlRd6MnDv8).

First and foremost is [Gaze](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gaze). This is a livereload module that will actually reload the node-webkit app after every change you make.  That's a far cry from the zip, run, test, make changes, zip, run, test cycle that many of us have been prisoners to in the past.

With that said, it sounds like you're just starting out with this platform. My suggestion is, whenever you find something you need to do, just google "npm *+whatever it is you're trying to do*" and there may very well be a module or some open source code to quickly help get you from point A to point B. Hope this helps!

Comment: I kept trying `$ nwjs` with no results, I hadn't realized the cli was still expecting `nodewebkit` :\

Answer (score 1):

another way i did is create alias for node webkit binary on `.bash_profile`

to simplify you can copy the nwjs file (`nwjs.app`) from downloaded source to Applications directory, and then open the `.bash_profile`

`sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`

and add the following line

```
# alias to nw
alias nw="/Applications/nwjs.app/Contents/MacOS/nwjs"
```

dont forget to refresh the bash profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

after that you can run your node webkit app by command

```
nw <path to your app>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help some people if they want see a quick output without much effort.

```
Folder
   index.html
   package.json
   nwjs (the extract executable file)
   js
   css
```

Then you just double click the nw.js, you could see the index running.

Such as:
[image]

Work on macOS 10.12.2 with nwjs v0.19.4